# JavaScript Recursive parsing on finding nested lists?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have(had) this problem where I needed to find nested lists ie.

```
<ul>
  <li>A
    <ul>
      <li>B
        <ul>
          <li>C
            <ul>
              <li>D</li>
              <ul>
                <li>E</li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I should get an output of ABC but what I'm after is being able to keep going deeper into the list regardless of how many there are. My attempts kept resulting in max call stack exceeded errors.

My plan was to detect if the parent had children which had  tags, if so, return that as a request to go deeper. But every time I kept trying to write this out in code, I wasn't writing the recursive part, I just kept duplicating code deeper (nested).

Here would be an example attempt:

Assuming the above is from HTML being accessed by JavaScript/jQuery as DOM content, I get the children per level eg. per

after the first .

```
if (jQuery(inpLine).is('ul')) {
  // note the depth and that this has ul, return as object
}
```

Then the above would trigger a function to go deeper, this is where I ran into problems as I would try to call the function itself but then would lose track/call stack exceeded. Same with using a secondary function.

I realize there is a serializeArray method assuming you had one input per line.

I don't know I'd like to figure it out on my own, I just feel dumb that I can't solve it like a brick wall I can't overcome.

I briefly was reading about it and saw something about trampoling which sounded like what I was trying to do with regard to keeping track of current depth/values and then going backwards with the values and concatenating the parts together.

This is a simple example, in the specific application I was working on each group could have inputs/other types of values that I needed to grab in order, I didn't have a problem with that it was the nesting.

Any hints/reading material would be helpful. I will figure it out eventually I guess haha thankfully it's not dier/needs to be solved now.

Comment: Have you considered getting all of the HTML as a string, removing all of the tags, then formatting it to whatever you need from that?

Comment: can you show your attempted function

Comment: Im not sure but I believe the DOM should not be like that. The li element should have only the text or the UL element, not both

Comment: @Shard wow that is a straightforward approach haha flew right over me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need recursion for that. The DOM already lists the elements in depth-first order, so using a selector (on `li` elements) will return those in the correct order.

What remains is to retrieve their text contents and concatenate the results.

Here is a solution both in ES3 jQuery code and plain ES6:

```js
// Plain ES6
var result = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'), li =>
    [...li.childNodes].filter(node => node.nodeType === 3)
            .map(node => node.nodeValue.trim()).join('')
).join(',');

console.log(result);

// jQuery & ES3
var result = $.map($('li'), function(li) {
    return $.map($(li).contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }), function (node) {
        return node.nodeValue.trim();
    }).join('')
}).join(',');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>A
    <ul>
      <li>B
        <ul>
          <li>C
            <ul>
              <li>D</li>
              <ul>
                <li>E</li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, I will have to run it/understand it. I don't argue with the list being returned in order. I don't understand how it keeps track of the uls inside which may have uls inside... But again the order. I do want to figure out a recursion approach but I guess I will do that on my own time, this approach solves the problem/simpler.

Comment: Don't complicate things when it is not necessary ;-)

Comment: Thanks that is a good point, even better when aware of alternatives. Time will tell I suppose, if I'm hired full time somewhere and how long I keep my job. Thanks for your time. This example is super simplified from the actual thing but this clearly points out a flaw in my thinking (or lack of).